# mongo does not allow updating createdAt

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
order = await Order.findOneAndUpdate({_id: orderId}, {
            $set: {
                created_at: new Date(sold_date),
            }
        }, {
            new: true
        });
```

I'm trying to manually update a previously created **created_at** field in the document. It seems that mongo avoids this update and nothing happens (only for **created_at**). Below is the field definition in model:

```
const orderSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    },
    {timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at'}});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `timestamps` to `false` in your `findOneAndUpdate`. Unfortunately, it's still not updated in the documentation.

[Reference](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8619)

```
order = await Order.findOneAndUpdate({_id: orderId}, {
            $set: {
                created_at: new Date(sold_date),
            }
        }, {
            new: true,
            timestamps: false
        });
```

Comment: I just added timestamps: false and it is not working yet.

Answer (score -1):

First you can **Unset** the field and then add the  created_at field again.

```
order = await Order.findOneAndUpdate({_id: orderId}, {
            {
             $unset: {created_at: 1}
             },
            $set: {
                created_at: new Date(sold_date),
            }
        }, {
                new: true, 
                runValidators : true
            });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work.